# Xcode 6 IB breaks with #define classname

Tags: xcode, class, interface, c-preprocessor, builder

I am building a System Preferences Pane. To avoid name collisions, Apple's method is to use #define to change class names like so:

```
#define SoundPref ComMycompanyPreferenceSoundPref
#define AlertController ComMycompanyPreferenceSoundAlertController
#define MicrophoneController ComMycompanyPreferenceSoundMicrophoneController
```

This is documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/Tasks/Conflicts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000706-BAJIAGFD

So I have a header file "ClassNameTranslation.h" which is added to every source (both .h and .m) with:

```
#import "ClassNameTranslation.h"
```

This worked perfectly in Xcode 4 and 5, but in Xcode 6, IB is not seeing the translated names. So if I instantiate an object in IB and give it a class of ComMycompanyPreferenceSoundPref, it will not see any of the outlets, nor will it allow other objects with a proper IBOutlet to hook up to it.

Only if I use the SoundPref class will IB be happy. Of course when I compile my code, it translates the SoundPref into ComMycompanyPreferenceSoundPref and nothing works because the objects in IB are not using the ComMycompanyPreference class name prefix.

I really do not want to have to use ridiculous long names like ComMycompanyPreferenceSoundPref throughout my source files and Xcode 4 and 5 made this possible.

Does anyone know how to make this work in Xcode 6 or some other way to use #define (or some other technique) to allow this to work again?

Comment: You problem shows that it is a bad idea to change the names of classes with define statements. Even if there is a reference to Apple stating that it is possible. It's just not a good idea. Xcode has autocompletions of long names. Therefore there isn't really a problem with long names, in my opinion.

Comment: Typing it is not the problem as autocompletion works well. The problem is actually reading the code which is difficult when it is littered with ComMycompanyPreference everywhere. As in:

[ComMycompanyPreferenceExternalProcessController sendRefreshAllNotification:self];

Comment: Instead of `ComMyCompany` use `CMC`.

Comment: My guess is that IB looks for code that looks like `@interface ClassName`, so if you just change the class declarations to not use the macros it might work.

Comment: It seems like you have to change the IBOutlets too so the IB will allow connections. I sure wish Apple hadn't broken this.